# Javafx Unable to attach contextmenu due to separate thread

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx

I have a Listener in my class. It looks it gets activated when a Belgian ID card is inserted and places the name in a textField. Now when this happens the program should also look if this name has already been inserted in the database, if it has not it should attach a contextmenu that is styled as a warning.

It goes wrong when im trying to attach the contextmenu, i know the code works as i have been using it in multiple places in my code. I get the following error:

### Error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:236)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:921)
    at javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:937)
    at javafx.stage.PopupWindow.showImpl(PopupWindow.java:454)
    at javafx.stage.PopupWindow.show(PopupWindow.java:399)
    at javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu.doShow(ContextMenu.java:287)
    at javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu.show(ContextMenu.java:262)
    at util.Validation.attachNotFound(Validation.java:140)
    at paginas.CheckOut$1.cardInserted(CheckOut.java:105)
    at be.belgium.eid.event.CardAlivePromptTask.run(CardAlivePromptTask.java:79)
```

### Listener

```
private final CardListener cl = new CardListener() {
        @Override
        public void cardInserted() {
            //de laadcirkel wordt zichtbaar wanneer het programma begint met een kaart te lezen.
            String fullName;
            System.out.println("card connected.");
            try {
                laadcirkel.setVisible(true);
                IDData data = id.getIDData();
                //voornaam ophalen, de format is nodig aangezien de reader de eerste naam en de tweede naam geeft.
                fullName = StringUtilities.format(data.get1stFirstname());

                //achternaam ophalen
                fullName = fullName + " " + data.getName();


                text_id.setText(fullName);
                text_id.autosize();

                CheckInOut c = lijst.getByCheckInName(text_id.getText());
                if (c != null) {
                    checkOut(c);
                } else {
                    Validation.attachNotFound(text_id);
                }
                laadcirkel.setVisible(false);

                //reset de layout om een visuele bug op te van in javafx.
                laadcirkel.getParent().getParent().setStyle("-fx-font: " + font + "px Tahoma;");

            } catch (EIDException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AanmeldPagina.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

It goes wrong when i call Validation.attachNotFound(text_id);

### Attach not found

```
public static void attachNotFound(TextField field) {
        field.setStyle("-fx-text-box-border: red ;-fx-focus-color: red ;");
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Not found");
        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
        menu.getStyleClass().add("error");
        menu.setAutoHide(true);
        menu.getItems().add(item);
        menu.show(field, Side.RIGHT, 10, 0);
        field.focusedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                menu.show(field, Side.RIGHT, 10, 0);
            }
        });
    }
```

I hope this is solvable with a small piece of code and that i dont have to rewrite a large portion of my program, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wrap the body of `attachNotFound` it like ...

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
    }
});
```

... everything will be fine.

This ensures that the code placed to the "..." will be executed on the JavaFX Thread. (The code from attachNotFound goes to the place of "...")

Comment: But I guess the error comes from this line:
`menu.show(field, Side.RIGHT, 10, 0);`.
So it is enough to wrap this line with the tequiniqe I mentioned. :)

Comment: I just wrapped the method inside the listener for now as i have to give a demo somewhere today, but thanks for clarifying ^^.